# Django models - Quantity field

Tags: django, django-models

I'm using Django to create a part inventory where I work. Here is a snippet of the models I have:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    number= models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price= models.FloatField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part)
```

So I have different groups (orders) with some parts in it.

What I want to do is to have a quantity property for the parts of my group. But if I want to add the quantity field to my Part object, each group will have the same quantity, which is not the correct behavior. How can I have my groups remember how much of each part they have?

Thanks for your input and I hope this is not a total noob question!

Comment: you need a `through` table

Comment: Don't use floats for prices, use a DecimalField.

Comment: Thanks Daniel Roseman, I was looking for a way to get that 2 decimal places!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need a [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/):

> The intermediate model is associated with the ManyToManyField using the through argument to point to the model that will act as an intermediary.

```
class Part(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    number= models.CharField(max_length=64)
    price= models.FloatField()

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part, through='GroupPart')
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a new [through table](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) between `Group` and `Part` that holds the quantity.